# Filter the dataframe, merge the data and add the count in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, count

**Actual Data:**

```
ID Name Count
ss  ih    5
tq  gg    5
xy  ab    5
st  gh    4
yz  ab    4
xv  ab    4
xy  bc    3
yz  rs    3
xy  cd    2
xv  cd    2
xv  mn    1
zq  jk    1
```

**Input:** I have a dataframe with lots of data. After taking a filter on Name("ab") we get this dataframe out of our whole data for example:

```
ID Name Count
xy  ab    5
yz  ab    4
xv  ab    4
```

Now taking the above IDs I filter the whole dataset file and we get

```
ID Name Count
xy  ab    5
xy  bc    3
xy  cd    2

ID Name Count
yz  bc    5
yz  ab    4
yz  rs    3

ID Name Count
xv  ab    4
xv  cd    2
xv  mn    1
```

**Desired Output:** I want to merge all the 3 dataframe we got into the first ID only and add the count

```
ID Name Count
xy  ab   13
xy  bc    8
xy  cd    4
xy  rs    3
xy  mn    1
```

**Code**: I know the code but don't know how to implement it here.

```
merge: df=pd.merge(df_1,df_2, how="outer", on=["Name"])

count : df['Count'] = df.loc(df['Count'].value_counts())
```

**Imp point:** I have just taken 'ab' as the first filter as an example. I want to do it with all "Name" values. We just drop the rest of IDs (yz and xv) with each iteration.

Comment: Add the actual sample data, there might be even better, more efficient approach to tackle this question.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I have add the actual data now

Comment: There should be four rows after filtering on `ab`?

Comment: sorry my bad, let me correct that

Comment: `xv` has 2 records of `ab` 4 and 1 , so the total should be 14 and not 10?

Comment: And there's no row in the input with `ID`: `yz`, `Name`: `ab`, `Count`: `5` as in your second filtered data.

Comment: i had corrected everything, check again

Comment: @Anubhav - There's still no `yz, bc, 5` row. This is in your second filtered data again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
... ID,Name,Count
... ss,ih,5
... tq,gg,5
... xy,ab,5
... st,gh,4
... yz,ab,4
... xv,ab,4
... xy,bc,3
... yz,rs,3
... xy,cd,2
... xv,cd,2
... xv,mn,1
... xv,ab,1
... zq,jk,1"""))
>>> df
    ID  Name    Count
0   ss  ih      5
1   tq  gg      5
2   xy  ab      5
3   st  gh      4
4   yz  ab      4
5   xv  ab      4
6   xy  bc      3
7   yz  rs      3
8   xy  cd      2
9   xv  cd      2
10  xv  mn      1
11  xv  ab      1
12  zq  jk      1
```

First, we can save the `serie` filtered on `ab` :

```py
>>> serie_name_filtered = df[df['Name']=='ab']['ID'].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> serie_name_filtered
0    xy
1    yz
2    xv
3    xv
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Then, we filter the whole `DataFrame` on the `ID` from the `serie` above :

```py
>>> df_filtered = df[df['ID'].isin(serie_name_filtered)]
>>> df_filtered
    ID  Name    Count
2   xy  ab      5
4   yz  ab      4
5   xv  ab      4
6   xy  bc      3
7   yz  rs      3
8   xy  cd      2
9   xv  cd      2
10  xv  mn      1
11  xv  ab      1
```

Next step, we use a `groupby` to get the `sum` of the `Count` column like so :

```py
>>> df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('Name')['Count'].sum().to_frame().reset_index(drop=False)
>>> df_grouped
    Name    Count
0   ab      14
1   bc      3
2   cd      4
3   mn      1
4   rs      3
```

To finish, we can add the `ID` column with the first `ID` from the serie `serie_name_filtered` to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df_grouped['ID'] = serie_name_filtered[0]
>>> df_grouped[['ID', 'Name', 'Count']]
    ID  Name    Count
0   xy  ab      14
1   xy  bc      3
2   xy  cd      4
3   xy  mn      1
4   xy  rs      3
```

To do it for all names in `Name` and save the result in a `dict` :

```py
>>> def my_function(name):
...     serie_name_filtered = df[df['Name']==name]['ID'].reset_index(drop=True)
...     df_filtered = df[df['ID'].isin(serie_name_filtered)]
...     df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('Name')['Count'].sum().to_frame().reset_index(drop=False)
...     df_grouped['ID'] = serie_name_filtered[0]
...     return df_grouped[['ID', 'Name', 'Count']]

>>> result = {}

>>> for name in df['Name'].unique():
...     result[name] = my_function(name)

>>> result
{'ih':    ID Name  Count
       0  ss   ih      5,
 'gg':    ID Name  Count
       0  tq   gg      5,
 'ab':    ID Name  Count
       0  xy   ab     14
       1  xy   bc      3
       2  xy   cd      4
       3  xy   mn      1
       4  xy   rs      3,
 'gh':    ID Name  Count
       0  st   gh      4,
 'bc':    ID Name  Count
       0  xy   ab      5
       1  xy   bc      3
       2  xy   cd      2,
 'rs':    ID Name  Count
       0  yz   ab      4
       1  yz   rs      3,
 'cd':    ID Name  Count
       0  xy   ab     10
       1  xy   bc      3
       2  xy   cd      4
       3  xy   mn      1,
 'mn':    ID Name  Count
       0  xv   ab      5
       1  xv   cd      2
       2  xv   mn      1,
 'jk':    ID Name  Count
       0  zq   jk      1}
```

Comment: Just 1 thing, I have just taken ab filter as an example, i want to do it with all "Name" values. We just drop the IDs (yz and xv)

Comment: You can take all the code above and put it in a `function` that take a parameter `name`. Then you can extract all the different names using a for loop like :   
`for name in df['Name'].unique():`
    `my_function(name)`

Comment: The end of the answer has been updated to apply on all names. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @tlentali , I want to add another functionality, I want to remove the ids which are repeated in another key. Like in the final output for "ab" containing "xy" id is also repeated in "bc" key. So i want to remove "bc" value and take only "ab". Hope you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
s=set(df.loc[df.Name.eq('ab'), 'ID'])

res = df[df.ID.isin(s)].groupby('Name')['Count'].sum().reset_index()

res['ID']='xy'

res=res[['ID', 'Name', 'Count']]

>>> print(res)

   ID Name  Count
0  xy   ab     14
1  xy   bc      3
2  xy   cd      4
3  xy   mn      1
4  xy   rs      3
```

Comment: Just 1 thing, I have just taken ab filter as an example, i want to do it with all "Name" values. We just drop the IDs (yz and xv). The actual data contains thousands of data.